# what's the difference between two command, one I enter from home and another from project directory?

Tags: xslt, ant, build.xml

**Point one** gives incorrect `xslt` report , gives some old report, when all test cases passed or failed. I don't know where it is saving it, because I clean (ant clean) old reports and generate new ones everytime i execute build.xml

**Point two** gives perfect xslt report, as expected (pass or fail).

```
 1.kris@kris-Satellite-C660:~$ ant -buildfile /home/kris/Desktop/myproject/build.xml run
```

and

```
 2. kris@kris-Satellite-C660:~/Desktop/myproject $ ant run
```

Comment: You're probably using relative paths in your `build.xml`.  Turning those into absolute ones should work for you.

Comment: But, how to identify relative or absolute path in build.xml and how can I turn them to absolute??

Comment: Look at the variables in order to figure.  Print those if you need to.